# Are there some open translation data (include reference data and candidate data )to calculate BLEU score?

Tags: python, machine-translation, bleu

Are there are some open machine translation data include candidate and reference data for calculating BLEU scores. 100 rows data of candidate and reference data are ok for me to implement BLEU in python. Thanks!

Comment: Try downloading this: https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/packages/models/wmt15_eval.zip Unzip and there's a readme inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any parallel text corpora. Plenty of open datasets are available in this regard. Have a look at this: http://www.statmt.org/europarl/

Comment: thanks, but I also want to the candidate data , not just reference data.